# How can I detect refused connections with libpcap?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, libpcap

I want to detect any connection that got refused in my system using libpcap.

I tried to do that with the next filter:

```
"tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-rst) == (tcp-rst)"
```

but the REST flag doesn't insure that the connection was refused it also can indicated that the connection just closed.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

TCP connection could be failed to start, actively refused or simply ignored.

- Failed to start means that host made an ARP or NDP request to get the MAC address of a host but received no reply, so the SYN packet was not even sent.
- Actively refused include TCP RST, ICMP Destination Port Unreachable and ICMP Destination net unreachable.
- Ignored is usually caused by Firewall rules it shows when you have a TCP SYN with no matching TCP SYN-ACK reply.

You asked explicitly for "refused", so that means you will need to add `icmp-unreach` and `icmp6-destinationrunreach`.

I would recommend in general to use, Wireshark/Tshark filters rather than using tcpdump filters, since pcap filters can only detect "active refusal" but not "no response/ TCP SYN ingored", see also https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html